# GWT JSNI javascript to Java not working

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am trying to invoke a Java Method from my Javascript code. This is for a Windows Phone 7 app using Phonegap.

I have the following in my javascript code.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 function onBackKeyDown(){

    }
```

And in my Java code I have the following.

```
  public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
    $wnd.onBackKeyDown = 
        $entry(this.@com.mycompany.myapp.client.MyApp::hideSettingsWidgets());

    }-*/;
```

Then in the on onModuleLoad() I am calling it like so:

```
MyApp.exportStaticMethod();
```

It does not work I have an alert in the `hideSettingsWidgets()` but it never gets shown.

****EDIT****
Here is some more code. The EventListener is not added in the Javascript. It is specifically added withing the java code. I could not get the listeners to register originally so here is what I added.

```
public static native void removeBackListener() /*-{
   $wnd.removeTheListener();
}-*/;
```

And in my JavaScript

```
function removeTheListener(){
        document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

        }
```

Here is my call to `hideSettingsWidgets()`

```
public void hideSettingsWidgets(){
        for(int i=0;i<settingsScreenWidgets.length;i++){
            settingsScreenWidgets[i].setVisible(false);
        }
        alertString("Working");
        removeBackListener();



    }
```

And I am calling the method you gave me inside `showSettingsWidgets()`

p

```
rivate void showSettingsWidgets(){
        for(int i=0;i<settingsScreenWidgets.length;i++){
            settingsScreenWidgets[i].setVisible(true);
        }
        setCurrentImage();
        setOnOffImage();
        setupJavaHandler();

    }
```

It does seem to be adding the EventListener that is inside your

```
public native void setupJavaHandler() /*-{
      var app = this;
      var onBackKeyDown = $entry(function() {
        app.@com.mycompany.myapp.client.MyApp::hideSettingsWidgets();
      });
      $doc.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }-*/;
```

So I am not sure where I am going wrong. I did not add the ArrayList<> you mentioned because was not sure to and the Event Listener was not running when page was Loaded.

Seems like `showSettingsWidgets()` never gets run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addEventListener` code is probably running when the page loads, right? This will map your empty function `onBackKeyDown` to the backbutton event. Then, when your module loads, you attempt to *redefine* the `onBackKeyDown` function to be a new one - but the old one was already attached to the event you are trying to listen to.

This is roughly the equivalent of this (with strings instead of listener functions):

```
// first, make the thing to hold the 'listener', and define the first one
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
String onBackKeyDown = "abcd";
strings.add(onBackKeyDown);

// then, redefine the string, but don't change the list!
onBackKeyDown = "zyxw";

assert strings.contains(onBackKeyDown) : "Whoops, reassigned, but not added!";
```

To fix this, you need a cross between what you are doing in your other question, [Adding Eventlisteners to document with GWT JSNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950717/adding-eventlisteners-to-document-with-gwt-jsni), and what you are doing here. Wrapping the Java function in an `$entry` call, and passing that to `$doc.addEventListener` makes the most logical sense (though I don't know a lot about WP7).

```
public static native void setupJavaHandler() /*-{
  var onBackKeyDown = $entry(this.@com.mycompany.myapp.client.MyApp::hideSettingsWidgets());
  $doc.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}-*/;
```

One more thing - remembering that we are writing JavaScript in that native code, what is going to be `this` when that `hideSettingsWidgets()` method is called? JavaScript doesn't know that all Java instance methods need a `this` to run on (and JavaScript has no problem running methods for object A on B - `A.method.call(B)` is totally legal, and often helpful). We need to be sure that `this` means what we think it does:

```
public static native void setupJavaHandler() /*-{
  var app = this;
  var onBackKeyDown = $entry(function() {
    app.@com.mycompany.myapp.client.MyApp::hideSettingsWidgets();
  });
  $doc.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}-*/;
```

Edit: Oops, turns out your method was static anyway, so `this` doesn't actually mean anything! Either change `exportStaticMethod`/`setupJavaHandler` to be non static and call it directly (probably in your `onModuleLoad` as you have it now), or pass in an instance to call `hideSettingsWidgets()` on, like we are doing with `app` in the previous sample.

```
public native void setupJavaHandler() /*-{
  var app = this;
  var onBackKeyDown = $entry(function() {
    app.@com.mycompany.myapp.client.MyApp::hideSettingsWidgets();
  });
  $doc.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}-*/;
// in onModuleLoad:
setupJavaHandler();
```

or

```
public static native void setupJavaHandler(MpApp app) /*-{
  //var app = this;
  var onBackKeyDown = $entry(function() {
    app.@com.mycompany.myapp.client.MyApp::hideSettingsWidgets();
  });
  $doc.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}-*/;

// in onModuleLoad:
MyApp.setupJavaHandler(this);
```

Comment: Hi. The addEventListener code is not added or running when the page loads it is specifically added in the java code. I also remove it by calling a javascript function. I have added my relevant code above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also just to be sure do I still need the empty onBackKeyDown function in my hosted html page?

Comment: It must be working right. I downloaded GWT Phonegap and it is doing the same thing. I would not be surprised if IE on mobile does not support JSNI fully.

Comment: Hi I have confirmed it was an issue with GWT JSNI. I made a plain HTML5 app and the 'backbutton' code is working right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your GWT app integrates with Phonegap, but if it is running locally on the browser (rather than loaded from a server) you need to make sure GWT is using the `ie6` user agent target.